# How to achieve ionic permissions on first load

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

My app currently asks for permissions when users open activities, I would like to have those permissions on app first load.

## Example

One of my components (activity) needs callNumber permission and asking for this permission won't be popup until user opens that component, I would like to have that permission popup when user install the app for first time instead of when user goes to that specific activity.

## Code

`MyComponent.ts` (my custom component `activity` that calling happen in that page)

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';

constructor(
    private callNumber: CallNumber,
) {...}

callEmergencies(event: any) {
    this.callNumber.callNumber(event, true)
    .then(res => {
        Toast.show({
        text: 'Calling ' + res + ' ...'
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        Toast.show({
        text: 'something went wrong.'
        });
    });
}
```

`App.module.ts` (main module)

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';

providers: [
    CallNumber,
],
```

`app.component.ts` (Main component)

Has nothing about `CallNumber` plugin.

## Question

How can I achieve that logic (asking permissions on first launch instead of in each activity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible or preferable. The new permissions paradigm is to request permissions when needed ('in context'). This way, the user should be in no doubt as to *why* you are requesting permission.

From the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting):

> Ask for permissions in context, when the user starts to interact with the feature that requires it.

iOS shares this [idea](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/):

> Request personal data only when your app clearly needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should embed all features on the first page without calling them in the  front end